# Json Individual Links in Table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have one page with a json table pulling in information from the json api. This works fine. Now my issue is, On the far right column i'm wanting a link to another page of mine, This link will be a unique link. At the moment, As you can see by the code, i can get it to link to the html page 12345, But all the rows link through to this. Which does not help Ha!

I'm ideally wanting the first button to link to 1.html then second button to link to 2.html and so on and so forth.

Here is the code i have so far.

```
          for(var i =0;i < json.results.collection1.length;i++) {

             var title = json.results.collection1[i].Name.text;

             var venue = json.results.collection1[i].Venue.text;
             var date = json.results.collection2[i].Date;
             var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='12345.html'>Link</button>";



             $("#apple").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+venue+"</td><td>"+date+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
           $("#apple").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
           }

     },
```

Obviously all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Sam

Comment: could you not do `var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='" + i + " .html'>Link</button>";`

Comment: Not sure how that would work personally, Little new to json coding, Surprised i got this far;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to explain the comment above

The link you're creating is a `<button>` but really it's just a string.
So by concatenating the URL part of the string based on something (like your i index in your loop) you can change it to anything you want.
so for example :

```
var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='" + i + " .html'>Link</button>";
```

this gives an element that looks like :

```
<button  class='redirect-button' data-url='0.html'>Link</button>
```

would give you 0.html, 1.html, etc (change the `data-url='" + i + " .html'` to `data-url='" + (i+1) + " .html'` and you get 1.html, 2.html, 3.html...)

or if you can change the API to give you a proper link in the return you can make it a bit more readable with:

```
var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='" + json.results.collection2[i].LinkUrl + " .html'>Link</button>";
```

results in :

```
 <button  class='redirect-button' data-url='abcd.html'>Link</button>
```

assuming the return is called `LinkURL` and it's value is 'abcd'

Finally you append this string to the `$("#apple")` element and then the click event is added that looks for the data-url value and changes the current browser location to that new value.

Comment: Hi there, Thats great, Would i For example be able to put in `(i+Pear)` to get pear1 pear 2? or? I mean i can do it fine with numbers but would be better with text:)

Comment: no you'd want to do `data-url='pear" + (i+1) + " .html'` to get pear1, pear2 just think of everything inbeteen the quotes as if it were already written on the page, and then the `+ whatever here +`  to be additional javascript to create a new number like in this case `i+1` followed by more stuff in quotes that might as well already be written on the page. (which by the way is how you get the `.html` extension on your links)

Comment: Cool, Just discussing, Thinking it may be better to do unique links, TYVM!

Comment: Hi @dave , Could you answer me this, once the date has passed, one of the json results gets removed, meaning there would be two items in said table. so at the moment as it stands, say if i have 3 links 255 256 and 257 and 255 disappears, 256 would become 255 and 257 would become 256 correct? Meaning if someone bookmarked a page the page would not exist. Ideas?

Comment: @SamRoberts Yes that sounds correct. The trouble is your approach is to just have a unique link to each index like 255.html, 256.html, 257.html. A better way is if the json object has a unique identifier that's part of the database itself (say id, or LinkURL) and then build a page like `edit.html?id=" + json.results.collection2[i].id` instead to make a edit.html?id=255 for example. Then on the edit.html page have it look up entry 255, and say here's the info you're looking for, and if 256 is removed then it says, sorry, this is no longer here, So even bookmarks would at least show something.